# Is Nhibernate using ADO.NET for connecting to database?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ado.net, dataprovider

What is the data provider for nhibernate? Is it ADO.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate.
It shows what tools/drivers are used to connect to different databases. for example:

> Oracle 9i and 10g are supported, both using Microsoft driver (System.Data.OracleClient) and using Oracle driver (Oracle.Data.OracleClient).

Or:

> To work with Firebird, install the latest Firebird .NET Data Provider.

I'm not sure whether it uses ADO.Net for SQL Server connections under the hood, <del>But it seems that it doesn't use ADO.Net for other database systems.</del>

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient and Oracle.Data.OracleClient are ADO.NET driver. You provide some useful information but your conclusion is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it [uses ADO.NET](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-overview) internally.